# Django Model validation based on a field value of another Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals, django-validation

I have this Django model:

```
   from accounts.models import Account    

   class BankOperation(models.Model):     
       created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
       account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       operation_import = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

I want to make sure that the `operation_import` is not higher than `account.balance`
what is the official way to this? I have seen some answers talking about overriding the save() method but others advise against it.

should i add a pre-save signal and throw some kind of exception?

Is there a way to create a field validator that accepts parameters?
so maybe something like:

```
   def validate_bank_operation_import(value, account_balance): 
   if value > account_balance:
         raise ValidationError("Bank operation import is higher than account balance!")
```

and inside my model i change the field to:

```
operation_import = models.FloatField(default=0.0, validators=[validate_bank_operation_import])
```

But can i pass parameters to a validator? if yes, how do I do it?

perhaps there is another to do this validation!

Comment: I don't know who "advises" against overriding `Model.save()` but that's complete BS.  Even [the doc explicitely tells it's ok](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects): " If you want customized saving behavior, you can override this save() method"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Override `clean` on the model?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) The validation process is described in detail in the doc, which includes use of this method to implement custom validation. Since it's a bound method it has access to `self` and thence `self.account.balance`.

Comment: Thanks! I thought the answer would be overriding a method but I could not find it on my own. Could you tell me where should I invoke the clean() method? in the documentation it says: 
_Note, however, that like Model.full_clean(), a model’s clean() method is not invoked when you call your model’s save() method._

Comment: is it good practice to override save() method like this: should i call full_clean() or directly clean()  ?

`def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        return super(BankOperation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: apparently it works even without calling the save() method. overriding the clean() method seems to work just fine for now. Thank you for your answer

Comment: I can't think of any case where overriding a method followed by returning the result of calling its superclass, can be different from  performing the same operations on the object instance from outside immediately  before calling the non-overridden method directly.

Comment: [As mentionned in the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) (which you should read, really),  "When you use a ModelForm, the call to is_valid() will perform these validation steps for all the fields that are included on the form"

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers But i am not using a ModelForm. 
I got confused by "_Note that full_clean() - or clean() - will not be called automatically when you call your model’s save() method_" but now i understand that i'm only supposed to call full_clean() when manually creating and saving the object and not creating it from the admin page.

Comment: The admin automagically creates a ModelForm for you (if you don't explicitely provide one) ;-)